# How do I use InputFilter to max number of characters in an EditText in Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dip" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtMarketName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="17sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgDelete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/edit_clr_tab" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The xml looks like :

[image]

Java Code:

```
public class EditTextLocker {
private EditText editText;

private int charactersLimit;

public EditTextLocker(EditText editText) {

    this.editText = editText;

    editText.setOnKeyListener(editTextOnKeyListener);
}

private OnKeyListener editTextOnKeyListener = new OnKeyListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
            startStopEditing(false);
        }

        return false;
    }
};

private TextWatcher editTextWatcherForCharacterLimits = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {            


        if (!editText.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {

            int editTextLength = editText.getText().toString().trim()
                    .length();

            if (editTextLength >= charactersLimit) {

                startStopEditing(true);

            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
};

public void limitCharacters(final int limit) {

    this.charactersLimit = limit;
    editText.addTextChangedListener(editTextWatcherForCharacterLimits);
}

public void unlockEditText() {

    startStopEditing(false);
}

public void startStopEditing(boolean isLock) {

    System.out.println("Start Stop Edit ==============> : " + isLock);

    if (isLock) {

        editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter() {
            @Override
            public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start,
                    int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

                return len < 1 ? dest.subSequence(dstart, dend)
                        : "";
            }
        } });

    } else {

        editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter() {
            @Override
            public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start,
                    int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
                return null;
            }
        } });
    }
}
}
```

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
EditText editText1;
ImageView imageView1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMarketName);

    imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgDelete);

    final EditTextLocker locker1 = new EditTextLocker(editText1);
    locker1.limitCharacters(60);

     editText1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (!hasFocus) {
                imageView1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else {
                imageView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });

    imageView1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            editText1.setText("");
        }
    });
}
}
```

The problem is that Stop appearing after 60 character,  but it still continues to type, except that text just doesn't appear, but however, it does appear in the "buffer" (meaning the suggestion thing)

and another problem is that after call imageview1 onClick event, type is continue but text is not display in edit text

Answer (score 0):

Following Code Snippet will help you to Handle inPut Filer 
for me it Works Like a Charm

```
  InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() { 
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, 
Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) { 
                for (int i = start; i < end; i++) { 
                        if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(source.charAt(i))) { 
                                return ""; 
                        } 
                } 
                return null; 
        } 
}; 

edit.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter});
```